# Automagic rollback of a junction table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There is a CMS system based on PostgreSQL, Python and SQLAlchemy. The publication part of the system is based on a structure:

Each entity of "Portal"s can have many "Page"s.

```
Portal >--to many(junction_table_1)--< Page
```

Let's imagine we have a portal with some web pages. 
At some point of time the design is changed - the old pages are removed and the new ones are added as well as all config files. **Let's call this point in time (T)**. Starting from that point the new web pages show up.

There is an error with one of the forms. After submitting it says there is a session problem. 
This error can be replicated on each and every machine and web browser and no further issues are visible.

Magic starts here:
There is one identified computer in the office which - if the mentioned error is caused from it - results with extraordinary change in the database. 
The state of the table "junction_table_1" is **reverted to the point in time before (T)**. The "portal" shows up all the old web pages in relations as well as to the users. Just to say it clearly: it's not the whole database. It's **just** that one junction table.

I know "it is not possible" but I've seen it replicated with that single machine over and over again.

We have checked locks on the database, hanging rollbacks etc. Nothing there. No scripts, triggers, procedures - the scheme contains only tables and sequences.

Any hints? Tools? Ideas where to start looking for some explanation? I need a Wizard to take part in an adventure...

Comment: While this sounds interesting, it is lacking a [mcve], and as such not useful for future readers.

Comment: Ilja I do know it, but without publishing the whole source code of the system which is huge I can't replicate it in any other way. That's why I asked for hints and suggestions rather than solutions... Thx!

Comment: Log all the SQL and figure out what actually happens.